# No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Bom Dia, estou com esse erro :

`No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.`

estou entrando na view de cadastro e esta me voltando essa menssagem,
tentei corrigilo não consegui eu tbm tentei colocar uma view mas tbm falhou

esse é o codigo da view de cadastro:

[image: View_De_Cadastro]

```js
package com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.database.DadosOpenHelper;
import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.dominio.entidades.Cliente;
import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.dominio.repositorio.ClienteRepositorio;

public class ActCadCliente extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText edtNome;
  private EditText edtEndereco;
  private EditText edtEmail;
  private EditText edtTelefone;
  private ConstraintLayout layoutContentActCadCliente;

  private ClienteRepositorio clienteRepositorio;

  private SQLiteDatabase conexao;

  private DadosOpenHelper dadosOpenHelper;

  private Cliente cliente;




  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.act_cad_cliente);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
    edtEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEndereco);
    edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    edtTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTelefone);

    layoutContentActCadCliente = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutContentActCadCliente);

    criarConexao();
  }

  private void criarConexao() {

    try {

      dadosOpenHelper = new DadosOpenHelper(this);

      conexao = dadosOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

      Snackbar.make(layoutContentActCadCliente, "Conexão criada com Sucesso", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("OK", null).show();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

      android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      dlg.setTitle(R.string.title_erro);
      dlg.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
      dlg.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_ok, null);
      dlg.show();

    }
  }

  private void confirmar() {

    cliente = new Cliente();

    if (validaCampos() == false) {

      try {

        clienteRepositorio.inserir(cliente);

        finish();

      } catch (Exception ex) {

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlg.setTitle(R.string.title_erro);
        dlg.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        dlg.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_ok, null);
        dlg.show();

      }

    }



  }

  @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
  private boolean validaCampos() {

    boolean res = false;

    String nome = edtNome.getText().toString();
    String endereco = edtEndereco.getText().toString();
    String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
    String telefone = edtTelefone.getText().toString();


    if (res = isCampoVazio(nome)) {
      edtNome.requestFocus();
    } else
    if (res = isCampoVazio(endereco)) {
      edtEndereco.requestFocus();
    } else
    if (res = !isEmailValido(email)) {
      edtEmail.requestFocus();
    } else
    if (res = isCampoVazio(telefone)) {
      edtTelefone.requestFocus();
    }

    if (res) {

      AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      dlg.setTitle("Aviso");
      dlg.setMessage(R.string.message_campos_invalidos_brancos);
      dlg.setNeutralButton(R.id.action_ok, null);
      dlg.show();

    }

    return res;

  }

  private boolean isCampoVazio(String valor) {

    boolean resultado = (TextUtils.isEmpty(valor) || valor.trim().isEmpty());
    return resultado;
  }

  private boolean isEmailValido(String email) {

    boolean resultado = (!isCampoVazio(email) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches());
    return resultado;

  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_act_cad_cliente, menu);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {

      case R.id.action_ok:
        confirmar();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Botão OK Selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;

      case R.id.action_cancelar:

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Botão OK Selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();

        break;



    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

esse é do inicio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
package com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.database.DadosOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ActMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView lstDados;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ConstraintLayout layoutContentMain;

    private SQLiteDatabase conexao;

    private DadosOpenHelper dadosOpenHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        lstDados = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lstDados);

        layoutContentMain = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutContentMain);

        criarConexao();

    }

    private void criarConexao(){

        try{

            dadosOpenHelper = new DadosOpenHelper(this);

            conexao = dadosOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            Snackbar.make( layoutContentMain, R.string.message_conexao_criada_com_sucesso, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction(R.string.action_ok, null).show();

        }catch(Exception ex){

            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dlg.setTitle(R.string.title_erro);
            dlg.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            dlg.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_ok, null);
            dlg.show();

        }
    }

    public void cadastrar(View view){

        Intent it = new Intent(ActMain.this, ActCadCliente.class);
        startActivity(it);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_act_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro que você tente com `findViewById (android.R.id.content)`.

Isto é o que funcionou para mim:

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

É por ai.

Comment: Cara deu erro no resp